# Need to go to a named link and execute a javascript at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hyperlink which goes to a named link. `<a href="#question">`
I needed it also to execute a Javascript so I did:

```
`<a href="javascript:SomeFunction();#question">`
```

which didn't work. I guess I have to jump to the named link from Javascript. How do I go to named link from Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the named anchor in the `href` and either use `onclick` or register the event on the `<a>` through javascript.

So either:

```
<a href="#question" onclick="SomeFunction();">
```

Or (this example makes use of [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) as an example, you could do the same with other javascript frameworks or with pure javascript):

```
<a href="#question" id="question_link">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('question_link').observe('click', SomeFunction);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Window.location.hash="question"

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = "location here"
```

this will redirect to whatever url

**EXAMPLE:** window.location = "#header"

OR if using a framework like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

```
$('a.cool').click(function(){
    someFunction(this);
    window.location = "#hash";
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<a href="javascript:SomeFunction();document.location='#question'">
```